# Reading integers separated by semicolon from a file in C++

Tags: c++

For a lab assignment we have been given a data file that looks like this:

```
12; 5;
15; 14;
21; 1;
1; 22;
```

The idea is to extract the first two integers and add them together. Nothing I've tried has been able to extract the second number (5) from the file. So far this is what I've got:

```
void add_numbers()
{
    std::ifstream in("fileio-data-1.txt");
    if (!in) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file, exiting." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int num1;
    int num2;


    in >> num1;
    std::cout << num1 << std::endl;
    in >> num2;
    std::cout << num2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << num1 + num2 << std::endl;

}
```

num1 has no issues and is always output as 12 but num2 ends up as 0. I've tried using `num1 = in.get()` and `num2 = in.get()` but that gives values of num1 = 49 and num2 = 50. I know I'm missing something here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Your program tries to input `;` into `num2`. This fails. Afterwards, the input stream is in failure state, and will stay in until you clear the failure. However, you should add an input for the `;`. You could e.g. read it into a `char` variable (and even check whether the read `char` really was the expected `';'`).

Comment: I knew it was going to be something very obvious that I was missing there. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to add a `char` variable to read the semi-colons,

```
int num1, num2;
char semi;
std::cin >> num1 >> semi >> num2 >> semi;
```

Comment: Christ, I knew it was something obvious... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for "extracting data" is "parse". (This will help you google search for similar issues in the future I believe)

To continue along your same line of thinking with what you've already got (using a stream), I think you'll need to loop through each character, comparing it with the output you need, similar to @john's answer.

```
int num1, num2;
char semi;

while (in >> num1 >> semi >> num2 >> semi){
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I was finding nothing when googling

Comment: I was curious if I could just put the stream operation in the condition. Hopefully it's fixed now.

Comment: :-) The only "magic" thing is that for every `in >> variable` you do, a reference to `in` is returned that will be used in the next `>> variable`. When the full expression is done, you're left with a reference to `in`, like `while(in)` - and streams return `not fail()` in boolean contexts - hence you can test if all the extractions succeeded in one go.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself parsing text input lines a lot so I created the following
utility function (probably influenced from my Perl scripting):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    size_t start;
    size_t end = 0;
    while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delim, end)) != std::string::npos) {
        end = str.find(delim, start);
        strings.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

and then you can split of each line using `;` as a delimiter

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    std::vector<std::string> str = split(line, ';');
    // could validate str[0] and str[1] here
    int num1 = std::stoi(str[0]);
    int num2 = std::stoi(str[1]);
    std::cout << (num1 + num2) << std::endl;
}
```

and as a bonus you can validate the strings to make it more robust in the face of bad input.